# PWM frequency completely off

Tags: pwm

Don't know anymore what todo, it seems like my hardware PWM frequency is off completely, I have set it to 10Hz (tried different values) and measure with the oscilloscope a frequency of about 5us, the duty_cycle is correct.

Tried different ways of configuring it, python, directly in shell and so on...

[image]
What could be wrong? Maybe something wrong with the internal clock?

[image]

Same result on both PWM channels (12 and 13). Measuring directly on the output pin.

Hope someone can help me out :)

Comment: Out of interest try `sudo pigpiod` then `pigs hp 12 10 500000` which should be a 10Hz square wave on GPIO 12.

Comment: `5 us` is not frequency .. it is a time interval

Comment: DO NOT post pictures of text post TEXT.